# TypeScript: Resolving Type Error in Dynamic Function Invocation based on Generic Filter Types

Tags: typescript, types, typeerror, typescript-typings

How can I modify my TypeScript code to resolve the type error in the last row (console.log(cf0.ftype)), ensuring proper type checking and invocation of the dynamically selected function from the ‘config’ object based on the generic ‘Filter’ type?

```
type FilterValues = {ip: string, magic: number}

type config = {
    [key in keyof FilterValues]: (data: FilterValues[key]) => string
}

const c: config = {
    ip: (data: string) => data,
    magic: (data: number) => data.toString()
}

type Filter<T extends keyof FilterValues> = {
    ftype: T;
    value: FilterValues[T]
}

const f: Filter<keyof FilterValues>[] = [{
    ftype: "magic",
    value: 6
}, {
    ftype: "ip",
    value: "1.2.3.4"
}]

const f0 = f[0]

console.log(c["ip"]("hello"))
console.log(c["magic"](5))
console.log(c[f0.ftype](f0.value))
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgNQIYIK4QM5QC8UA3nGAFxR7ApwB2A5gDRQC2GjcAxlfdmwBGqAL4AoMaEhRuAe3oAzOIyKkxUDVADaAawggoDKHpCyFsRMnRZceALpUAFABMMwDFXhJUmHPl36dgCURAB81LQMjGLiYnL0NDJU8UoqxCTqmuROru5UNHRMIYThuRjMmRocXLxQLm4eUPxCqMWlDQB0wLIAypFMjkExElLQXlYAPAAqUBAAHsj0zgQmZhbe1n544emVUAqjVFMA3HsAbjYQnpY+l3haU3bDcfKJCtcbE6vm47dboVo7KotBlNPtDlAAETVHiQipgi5+KgANhirFBmgO4CuUPIcPOlyokIAjB0AEwdADMHQALJCYk8XglgPsAAyqBRaVmM+J4WQICAdBCyRiObhaSF4uyOSEACwgCGFkKCQ15-MFwtF4uhnFh0oArCqmXyBUKRWKtApWR0sZBpVaOojcEagA)

Comment: You've hit the lack of direct support for *correlated unions* as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). The supported approach is refactoring to generics as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). Applying that technique to your example yields [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WPOXYm). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer or find a suitable duplicate target. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: That’s awesome! Great to know that’s a known issue. Your answer is great and really helped, but it raises another question. What happens if I change the value type of the config, instead of a function to be a dict with many functions like [here](https://shorturl.at/mpBCT). Do I need to define an apply function to each one of them? This is not clean.

Comment: That looks like you’re expanding the scope of the question. I’m not averse to considering it, but I’d rather get this question answered as asked first, since there is a good chance any answer I give to your modified example will lead to further modifications. Is that okay? Or do you need the new version handled in order to accept an answer?

Comment: I do need the new version to accept it. Do you want me to edit the original question?

Comment: Yes, if it is a requirement it should be in the question. It's unfortunate that you couldn't accept the answer to the question as asked and then ask a new question if you couldn't figure out the followup issue yourself, but that's your prerogative. I don't know right now if I have a solution to the new question (I haven't had a chance to look at it in detail).

Comment: Assuming you do decide to [edit], then the only way I can get TS to verify is to abstract it to be completely generic and then specify the types, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wvz7QW).  It's essentially a nested application of ms/TS#47109.  Does that fully address the question now? Tell me how you'd like to proceed.

Comment: Ok, so let’s keep the original question :). Your first answer was great. The last solution is also great, thanks man. Although it became very complex.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the compiler to validate `config[filter.ftype](filter.value)` as safe, it needs to see `config[filter.ftype]` as having a single function type, and to see `filter.value` as having a type appropriate for that function.

---

The first problem is that your `Filter<keyof FilterTypes>` type is not correct.  If you evaluate it, you get `{ ftype: "ip" | "magic", value: string | number }`, meaning that something like `{ ftype: "ip", value: 123 }` is possible, and that would of course be doing the wrong thing.  Imagine `c` were actually

```
const c: Config = {
    ip: (data: string) => data.toUpperCase(),
    magic: (data: number) => data.toFixed()
}
```

and you'd see that there would be a runtime error. So the compiler error is warning you of an actually valid concern. Still, you could fix this by redefining `Filter` so that a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) input becomes a union output.  You want to *distribute* your `Filter` definition across unions.  There are a few ways to do this, but the one that will work best is known as a *distributive object type*, as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). It looks like this:

```
type Filter<K extends keyof FilterValues> = { [P in K]: {
    ftype: P;
    value: FilterValues[P]
} }[K]
```

We make `Filter<K>` a [mapped type]([mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)) over `K` into which we immediately [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `K`, distributing the inner object type over unions in `K`.  You can test now that `Filter<keyof FilterValues>` evaluates to the union `{ ftype: "ip", value: string } | { ftype: "magic", value: number }`. This correctly prevents someone from crossing their wires with `{ ftype: "ip", value: 123 }`.

Unfortunately if you make this change, you'll still get the exact same error.

---

Your code is already part of the way there.  `FilterTypes` is the basic interface, and `Config` is the appropriate mapped type over that interface.  Your `Filter` type is a little inaccurate, since `Filter<keyof FilterTypes>` would actually be the unsafe `{ ftype: "ip" | "magic", value: string | number }`, when you really want `{ ftype:

Again, to validate `config[filter.ftype](filter.value)`, `config[filter.ftype]` needs to have a function type and `filter.value` needs to have the corresponding argument type.  But now that `filter` is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), the compiler sees `config[filter.ftype]` as being a *union* of functions, and `filter.value` is a *union* of arguments, and generally it's unsafe to call the former with the latter.

The compiler doesn't track the *identity* of `filter` here, just its type.  And so the analysis proceeds as if you had written ``configfilter1.ftype`where`filter1`and`filter2`might be different members of the union.  That is, the compiler loses the *correlation* between the two utterances of`filter`in the expression, even though we went out of our way to establish that correlation by fixing`Filter`'s type.

---

This lack of support for *correlated unions* is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  If you don't want to just use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to silence the warning, but instead want to get the compiler to actually verify what you're doing as safe, you can follow the steps laid out in microsoft/TypeScript#47109, which I referenced before.

That issue describes a refactoring away from unions toward [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), where everything is written in terms of some "basic" interface, and generic indexes into that basic interface or into mapped types over that interface.

Your code is already most of the way there.  `FilterTypes` is the basic interface, and `Config` is the appropriate mapped type over that interface.  And we have fixed `Filter` to be an indexed access into a mapped type over the basic interface.  The only thing left to do is to write the function call where `filter.ftype`'s type is a generic type [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a union, instead of a plain union.

You can't just declare a generic type parameter inline and use it. You need to wrap your code in a generic function instead.  So, let's do that:

```
function apply<K extends keyof FilterValues>(config: Config, filter: Filter<K>) {
    return config[filter.ftype](filter.value); // okay
}
```

That compiles just fine.  If you look, `filter.ftype` is of type `K`, and so `config[filter.ftype]` is of type `Config[K]` which evaluates to `(data: FilterValues[K]) => string`.  And since `filter.value` is of type `FilterValues[K]`, everything works. And the return type of `apply()` is `string`.

Of course we need to *call* `apply()`, so that looks like

```
apply(c, f[0]);
```

and works as expected.

---

Such refactoring might not be worth it to you, but this is currently the recommended approach to maintaining some semblance of type safety in the face of correlated union types.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgNQIYIK4QM5QC8UA3lHGAFxR7ApwB2A5gDRQC2GTcAxtQ9nYAjVFAC+AKAmhIUAMIB7BgDM4TIqQlRtUANoBpcgygBrCCAXLYiZOiy48AXWoAKACYZgGavCSpMOPgGjgCURAB8NHSMTBKSEjxKtFB88kqq6sQkWjoUrh5e1LT0zGGEkQUYAHTACgCqYJAochh4EC4hLDnanNyp7p7eUALCqGUVgzUK8AAeEG4dcVIy0L62ADyGEDPIDG4EZhZWa-72+JFZegAKRlD6zpo6UMor1FcA3N1QAG5nPjanQJ4XRXRxxcTBKSJBjJZT-PwodaHSzWBEBBzhXSODS6bJPF7gCDUABEvV4xK6T1+gWoADY4mw8ToCZASRQKV9qbgSQBGKoAJiqAGYqgAWYlxMESZTYBg8YBwJRQDCNBAgTZQba7famcwok52IHhFzQjLURQqNRsVQI+EbfThMJM7QoCDAbAoYymtS6G22KosiCOFx+1BVLkQEJLaF4BQICBVBAKJguFVgNUm626AAMoRCnyAA)